Why does Python not execute my given event handler function when it is provided as a non-static method rather than a static method? See coding below:
I can't seem to understand why the below coding does not give me the behavior I am looking for.
Expected Behaviour:

The coding below draws a graph and once I click on the legend Icon for the drawn graph, I expect 2 lines of text to appear: 1)"non-static event handler method working" & 2) "static event handler method working".

Actual Behaviour:

Once I click on the legend icon it is only the 2nd statement that appears on the terminal. This indicates that for some reason Python does not execute the event handler function, "nonstatic_onpick", possibly because it has been provided as a non-static method. Why is this the case? Have I made a syntax error somewhere? Is there a way to provide an event handler function as a non-static method? 

Sidenote:

(I understand that the below coding may not be the most elegant/efficient/readable algorithm but I have actually adapted this coding from another more complex use case that requires the algorithm to be in the current structure shown below.)

Coding:
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    class Setup_IntrctveLgnd():
        def __init__(self,legend,fig):
            lgndicons=legend.legend_handles
            lgndicons[0].set_picker(20)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", self.nonstatic_onpick)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", Setup_IntrctveLgnd.static_onpick)
        def nonstatic_onpick(self,event):
            print("non static event handler method working")
        def static_onpick(event):
            print("static event handler method working")

   fig,ax=plt.subplots()
   ax.plot([0,1,2,3], label="data")
   legend=plt.legend()
   Setup_IntrctveLgnd(legend,fig)
   plt.show()



Any help would be much appreciated.

Maybe due to this?: "The canvas retains only weak references to instance methods used as callbacks. Therefore, you need to retain a reference to instances owning such methods. Otherwise the instance will be garbage-collected and the callback will vanish.". You never assign the new Setup_IntrctveLgnd instance anywhere, so it will be destroyed. Try just doing  instance = Setup_IntrctveLgnd(legend,fig).

Massive thanks. Spent hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong but with your suggestion it seems to be working perfectly now..

Good to hear. You might want to reconsider the use of a class though. It's a bit odd to create a class just for the side effect of creating an instance. This looks like it should be just a function, which would make the issue you ran into impossible.

The problem is most likely a TypeError: nonstatic_onpick takes 2 positional argument but 1 was given or something similar. It tells you that the method nonstatic_onpick had an extra parameter. This might fix the problem:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    class Setup_IntrctveLgnd():
        def __init__(self,legend,fig):
            lgndicons=legend.legend_handles
            lgndicons[0].set_picker(20)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", self.nonstatic_onpick)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", Setup_IntrctveLgnd.static_onpick)
        def nonstatic_onpick(self, event=None):
            print("non static event handler method working")
        def static_onpick(event):
            print("static event handler method working")

   fig,ax=plt.subplots()
   ax.plot([0,1,2,3], label="data")
   legend=plt.legend()
   Setup_IntrctveLgnd(legend,fig)
   plt.show()

